# How to create a model using .edmx designer in visual studio 2012?

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, visual-studio-2012, edmx-designer

I'm new with Entity Framework 5.0. 
I'm looking for a tutorial on how to create a DB model using the .edmx designer in visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This video is an excellent tutorial:

> [I am creating a new database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj205424)
>
> Use Model First to define your model using boxes and lines and then
> generate a database.

---

Here's the MSDN doc on the subject:

[Entity Framework Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399249%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

From this main doc you can drill-down to a lot of topics including the one you want.